# SonarQube's Architectural Constraint rule template alternatives

Tags: java, sonarqube

I noticed the [Architectural Constraint rule template](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Spaghetti+Design) has recently been deprecated.

From [SONARJAVA-1774](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1774):

> This rule is targeting a scope out of our goals. That is why we are deprecating it.

Is there any alternative for enforcing architectural constraints through SonarQube's rules, or should I write my own custom Java rule for this purpose?

Comment: It may be related to the following discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/kMe1TZl24Ro